# Explanation of currying for zipWith ($)

Tags: haskell, currying

I have been trying to understand this piece of code but I'm not able to wrap it up clearly:

```
ghci > :t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
ghci > :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
ghci > let c = zipWith ($)
ghci > :t c
c :: [b -> c] -> [b] -> [c]
```

How does `[b -> c]` originate up in the above type signature ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for `zipWith ($)` to typecheck we must *unify* the type of `zipWith`'s first argument with the type of `($)`. I'll write them out together and with unique names to make it more clear.

```
zipWith :: (a        -> b -> c) -> [a]     -> [b] -> [c]
($)     :: ((x -> y) -> x -> y)
```

Thus, `zipWith` typechecks if and only if we can assume that `a ~ (x -> y)`, `b ~ x` and `c ~ y`. There's nothing stopping this unification from succeeding, so we can substitute these names back into the type for `zipWith`.

```
zipWith :: ((x -> y) -> x -> y) -> [x -> y] -> [x] -> [y]
($)     :: ((x -> y) -> x -> y)
```

And then proceed with application since everything matches up nicely now

```
zipWith ($) :: [x -> y] -> [x] -> [y]
```

which is equivalent up to the specific choice of type variable names with the type you saw.

Answer (score 2):

It's just context substitution and no magic there. Look:

```
ghci > :t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
ghci > :t ($)
($) :: (a' -> b') -> a' -> b'
```

Now consider `zipWith ($)`. It has type of `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]` where first argument is fixed, so we should pattern match `(a -> b -> c)` (type of a first arg) with `(a' -> b') -> a' -> b'` (type of `$`). Thus we have `a = (a' -> b')`, `b = a'`, `c = b'`. Substitute is back to the `zipWith`: `[a' -> b'] -> [a'] -> [b']` (first argument is fixed, so he disappear from type) and that's exactly what you got with type variables named differently.

Also, one might consider `zipWith` semantics: take zipper (first argument), and then zip two lists together. If your zipper is function application (`$` is function application, yes!) then when zipping two lists you just invoke elements of the first list with corresponding element of the second list. And function type reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

The actual letters assigned in the type signature are arbitrary and could be anything. You could just as easily write the type of ($) as

```
(x -> y) -> x -> y
```

It takes two arguments, a function taking a single argument, and a value to pass into the function.

The first argument to `zipWith` is a function taking two arguments `(a -> b -> c)`. Given the definition of `($)`, you choose `a` as `(x -> y)` and `b` as `x` then `c` is `y`, so you get the type of `zipWith ($)` as

```
[x -> y] -> [x] -> [y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite a bit our signature:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) :: a' -> b' -> c'
  where  -- pseudo-Haskell
    a' = a -> b
    b' = a
    c' = b


zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

And find, that

```
zipWith ($) :: [a'] -> [b'] -> [c']

zipWith ($) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
```

Comment: Can you use where syntax w/ type signatures?